# Kotlin confusion about mixing generics and inheritance

Tags: generics, inheritance, kotlin

```
    abstract class Human

    class Alien : Human()

    abstract class Foo<T>() {
        abstract fun foo(): T
    }

    class Too<Human>() : Foo<Human>() {
        override fun foo(): Human {
            return Alien()
        }
    }
```

Class Too() is a subclass of the abstract class Foo() which gives T the type Human. I would like to be able to return a subclass of Human() (Alien() in this example) from foo(), however I am getting a type mismatch error. Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: Your `Human` isn’t a type in the example - it’s a generic unbounded parameter called “Human”. Remove the generic declaration from `Too`. `class Too : Foo<Human>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it like this:

```
abstract class Human

class Alien : Human()

abstract class Foo<T>() {
    abstract fun foo(): T
}

class Too : Foo<Human>() {
    override fun foo(): Human {
        return Alien()
    }
}
```